# Wait for n executions of a method and then continue after complete

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a function that returns promise:

```
Setup.zoomIn() : Promise<void> {...}
```

I would like to use rxjs to invoke that function 5 times with delay of 1 second between each, like this:

```
let obs = Observable.create(observer => {
  let count = 0; 
  setTimeout(() => {
     Setup.zoomIn();
     count++;
     observer.next();          
  }, 1000);
  if (count === 5) {observer.complete();}
};

obs.subscribe(() =>
   console.log('zoomed out');
)};
```

Only and only when that is executed I would like to continue with execution to perform further steps:

```
obs.toPromise.then(() => {
   // do some stuff here but only after zoom has been invoked 5 times
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of observables for zoomIns functions and concat them with another Observable.

```
function zoomIn(i) {
  return new Promise(res => {
   setTimeout(()=>res(i), 1000);
 });
};

function anotherPromise() {
  return Rx.Observable.defer(()=> {
   return new Promise(res => {
     setTimeout(()=>res('anotherPromise'), 3000);
  });
 });
}

const zoonInList = Array(5).fill(0).map((x, i)=>i).map(i=>
   Rx.Observable.defer(()=> {
    return zoomIn(i);
 })
);

Rx.Observable.concat(...zoonInList, anotherPromise())
   .subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```